# How to create sublist from a list with filtered item?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a payload like below -

```
1,a1,21,31,b1
2,a2,22,32,b2
3,,23,33,b3
4,a4,,,b4
```

And trying to fetch every 2nd column from this string and put it into a list.

Expected Output:

```
[a1,a2,a4]
```

I tried below code but didn't get the desired output -

```
ListPayload = []
for line in ((payload.text).splitlines()):
    ListPayload.append(line)
```

By doing this I get the output like below -

```
['1,a1,21,31,b1','2,a2,22,32,b2','3,,23,33,b3','4,a4,,,b4']
```

And using below code to fetch 2nd column -

```
filteredList =[]
for i in range(len(ListPayload)):
    filteredList.append(ListPayload[i].split(",")[1])
```

And then I used below to get the desired output

```
result = [x for x in filteredList if x]
print(result)
```

Is there a better approach than this to get the desired output?

Comment: import your data in a `panda` dataframe then pick the desired column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
payload = '''1,a1,21,31,b1
2,a2,22,32,b2
3,,23,33,b3
4,a4,,,b4'''
col = 1  # you can extract any column
[line.split(',')[col] for line in ((payload).splitlines()) if line.split(',')[col]]  

Output:
## ['a1', 'a2', 'a4']
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing

```py
ListPayload = []
for line in ((payload.text).splitlines()):
    ListPayload.append(line)
```

you could simply write:

```py
lines = payload.text.splitlines()
```

(note that I have renamed 'ListPayload' to 'lines', but this might be a matter of personal preference)

And instead of:

```py
filterList =[]
for i in range(len(ListPayload)):
    filterList.append(ListPayload[i].split(",")[1])
```

you could write:

```py
result = [line.split(",")[1] for line in lines]
```

You *could* filter the results like this:

```py
result = [line.split(",")[1] for line in lines if line.split(",")[1]]
```

but in this case I would prefer a simple loop (to avoid calling `split()` multiple times in the above form).

**COMPLETE EXAMPLE**

Putting everything together results in the following code:

```py
result = []
lines = payload.text.split()
for line in lines:
    columns = line.split(',')
    if columns[1]:
        result.append(columns[1])

print(repr(result))
```

This outputs:

```
['a1', 'a2', 'a4']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easy via:

```
txt = '''1,a1,21,31,b1
2,a2,22,32,b2
3,,23,33,b3
4,a4,,,b4'''

result = [line.split(',')[1] for line in txt.splitlines() if line.split(',')[1]]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['a1', 'a2', 'a4']
```

Though that is a short solution the following is technically faster because it only calls `split` once per line:

```
txt = '''1,a1,21,31,b1
2,a2,22,32,b2
3,,23,33,b3
4,a4,,,b4'''
result = []
for line in txt.splitlines():
    desired = line.split(',')[1]
    if desired:
        result.append(desired)
print(result)
```

Comment: We're quite on the same line here. See my answer ;-)